# Can not apply css to svg icon inside mat-icon

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material2

Having a trouble in styling svg icon inside angular material.

controller:

```
mdIconRegistry.addSvgIcon('testAnimation', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`${svgPath}/icons/testAnimation.svg`));
```

template:

```
<a class="icon"><md-icon svgIcon="testAnimation"></md-icon></a>
```

style:

```
.icon .st9 {fill: black}
```

The problem is that this css rule is not applied to the icon - and I can't figure out why.

There is a path with such class in my svg image and it can be found via `document.querySelectorAll('.icon .st9')`. I even can change it's fill color using `document.querySelectorAll('.icon .st9')[0].style.fill = 'black'`.

When I insert svg in html directly without material - it works fine too.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that in your component.css file

```
:host ::ng-deep .icon .st9 {fill: black}
```

Or put your css rule in style.css, but make sure to encapsulate with the component's name to make sure it does not leak

```
app-your-component .icon .st9 {fill: black}
```

Comment: The other way is to change ViewEncasulation to none. I believe the `::ng-deep` and `/deep/` weren't going to stick around forever (I believe I read that somewhere at least)